# Getting OSError: [WinError 2] when using a makefile containing pip install to install dependencies

Tags: python, makefile, pip

I am getting a `ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Python310\\Scripts\\unidecode.exe' -> 'C:\\Python310\\Scripts\\unidecode.exe.deleteme'` error when I try running a make command that should install the developer dependencies for an open source project. I saw another post that resolves this issue by using the `--user` option for single commands. However, this is a large makefile and I cannot change the commands manually. Is there a way that I might be able to fix this without using the `--user` option?

**Edit 1**
I have found that the issue is entirely about running `pip install`. Using the `--user` option sets the installation path to the home directory. I would now like to find out if there is a way that I can change this permanently in order to not have to use the option.

Comment: Can you show a condensed `Makefile` that produces your issue?

Comment: Upon further research, I have found that the issue is entirely about pip. I will update the question to reflect this.